# How to have pgfplotstable ignore rows with no entries in certain columns?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have data from a large .csv file. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
TypeI,  TypeII,  Data
A,      ,        3
B,      ,        1
,       C,       4
,       D,       1
```

I've made symbolic x-coordinates for TypeII with `symbolic x coords={C,D}`. I'd like to *only* plot they TypeII data using `\addplot table[x=TypeII,y=Data]{\mydata};`.

When I try this, the problem is that it doesn't know what to do with the blank entries in the TypeII column. The error message is "Sorry, the input coordinate `' has not been defined with symbolic x coords={C,D}..."

Is there a simple parameter to tell `\addplot` to ignore row/column combinations that are incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

Try placing `nan` instead of an empty cell or missing value in your table. You also have the option to either jump the missing coordinate (`unbounded coords=jump`) or to interrupt the line (which is the default behavior: `unbounded coords=skip`). These options are relevant if `nan` appears somewhere in the middle of your data.

```
TypeI,  TypeII,  Data
A,      nan,     3
B,      nan,     1
nan,    C,       4
nan,    D,       1
```

Comment: This didn't quite work. Once symbolic coords are in use, it doesn't recognize 'nan' for what it should; it thinks it's another undeclared symbolic coord. But I added 'nan' to the end of the list of symbolic coords, and restricted the domain to exclude the last coord. I'll wait and see if there's a better approach, but this answer is helpful.